# Скрыть изображение с помощью тега <picture>

Tags: html

Есть тег `<picture>` и в нем `<source>` с помощью которого можно подключать разные изображения для разных разрешений.
Мне необходимо показывать определенные изображения только для больших разрешений, и чтобы они не грузились для маленьких.
Я пробовал не указывать файл

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 600px)">
  <img src="test.png">
</picture>
```

Но это не работает, картинка все равно подключается при маленьком разрешении.

Comment: не совсем понятно, Вы хотите "скрыть изображение" (как написано в тайтле) или именно "чтобы они не грузились" (как написано в тексте поста).

Comment: может быть лучше решать эту задачу на js?

Comment: Да, согласен, не совсем корректно. Нужно чтобы на маленьких разрешениях не грузились картинки, предназначенные для больших разрешений.  Ответ, данный humster_spb, подходит без применения js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если только для больших, то указывать надо не max-width, а min-width. Ну и в дефолтной картинке srcset не указывать - тогда для маленьких экранов ничего отображаться не будет:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/1f98fb5e-e06f-4ddc-afe7-c4a745ecea0e/s1200" media="(min-width: 600px)">
  <img srcset="" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Только этот метод не будет работать в браузерах ie 11 и ниже. Нужно смотреть поддержку тега <picture>

Comment: @AlexanderKhramov, а это здесь причём? Про поддержку вопроса не было.

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Я для тех кто наткнется на этот метод.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное можно решить Вашу задачу на jQuery:

```js
if ($(window).width() > 720) {
  $('#img').attr('src', 'images/big-file.png');
} else if ($(window).width() > 480) {
  $('#img').attr('src', 'images/middle-file.png');
} else {
  $('#img').attr('src', 'images/small-file.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="">
```